# How can I get post data into an array in CodeIgniter? post items are arrays

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

In CodeIgniter, I'm trying to accomplish a batch update from form inputs that share the same name. But don't know how to get post data into an array. A simplified view of the form is as follows:

```
<input name="id[]" value="1"/><input name = title[] value="some-title"/><input name     ="sort_order[]" value="1"/>

<input name="id[]" value="2"/><input name = title[] value="some-tuttle"/><input name="sort_order[]" value="2"/>

<input name="id[]" value="3"/><input name = title[] value="some-turtle"/><input name="sort_order[]" value="3"/>
```

In my controller I have this for now:

```
function set_sort_order(){
    $data = array(
        array('id' => 1,'sort_order' => 14),
        array('id' => 2,'sort_order' => 5),
        array('id' => 3,'sort_order' => 9)
    );
    $this->db->update_batch('press_releases', $data, 'id');//works!
    $this->load->view(pr_listing);
}
```

The array is hard-wired to test in the input_batch function, which is working. So how can I get the post data into an array?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
$id = $this->input->post('id');
$sort_order = $this->input->post('sort_order');
$data = array();
foreach($id as $key=>$val)
{
  $data[] = array('id'=>$val,'sort_order'=>$sort_order[$key]);
}
```

Comment: ok great @Naveed!

Answer (score 5):

Just by nature of the way the input fields are named using bracket notation (i.e. `fieldname[]`) will cause PHP to automatically populate data from these fields into an array.  Simple access them like:

```
$ids = $_POST['id'];
$titles = $_POST['title'];
// etc.
```

You can easily combine these into a multidimensional array

```
$final_array = array();
$length = count($ids);
for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
    $final_array[$i]['id'] = $ids[$i];
    $final_array[$i]['title'] = $titles[$i];
    // etc.
}
var_dump($final_array);
```

Note: I did not show any input data validation/cleansing steps in my example. You probably want to verify input  data exists, is in proper format, etc. before working with it.

Comment: Totally correct. Just to put this in codegniter format:
"$ids = $this->input->post('id');" I believe should do it.